# Collect all rows that have a change in some column during date interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have History table that contains a history log for changes against the target object and I want to select rows that have Value changed during some time period.

Example data:

```
TargetId  Value  CreatedUtcDateTime 
1         1      2018-03-09
1         1      2018-04-09
1         2      2018-04-10
2         3      2018-05-10
2         4      2018-06-10
2         5      2018-07-10
3         4      2017-08-10
3         1      2018-09-12
3         2      2018-10-13
```

Expected result for interval from '2018-01-01' to '2019-02-01' is:

```
TargetId OldValue NewValue CreatedUtcDateTime 
1        1        2        2018-04-10
2        3        4        2018-06-10
2        4        5        2018-07-10
3        4        1        2018-09-12
3        1        2        2018-10-13
```

So far I came up with the solution that is based on the windows functions:

```
select c1.TargetId as Coil, 
       c2.Value as OldValue, 
       c1.Value as NewValue, 
       c1.CreatedUtcDateTime as ChangeDate
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by TargetId order by CreatedUtcDateTime) as rowNum, 
     TargetId, 
     Value, 
     CreatedUtcDateTime  from History) c1
join ( select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by TargetId order by CreatedUtcDateTime) as rowNum, 
              TargetId, 
              Value, 
              CreatedUtcDateTime 
         from History) c2
  on c1.rowNum = c2.rowNum + 1 
 and c1.TargetId = c2.TargetId 
 and c1.Value != c2.Value 
 and c1.CreatedUtcDateTime > c2.CreatedUtcDateTime
 where c1.CreatedUtcDateTime > '2018-01-01' 
   and c1.CreatedUtcDateTime < '2019-02-01'
```

But this produces two full table scans and I want to avoid this. Is there more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you had a look at `LEAD` and `LAG`?

Comment: Yes, I did. But they expect you to specify how many rows you should look back or forward and I don't know how many rows it could be. It can be a two or three rows where value didn't change, as in my first example for target 1, and then the row where this value changed.

Comment: Your `ON` clause has `c1.rowNum = c2.rowNum + 1`. That's effectively specifying "1 row back". I don't see your point in the above comment, as the SQL you have tried contradicts it. :)

Comment: Both `LAG` and `LEAD` can make use of the `PARTITION BY` clause as well.

Comment: @Larnu  My bad, sorry, you are right. I should work more diligently on my SQL skills. Thanks, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select h.*
from (select h.*, lag(value) over (partition by targetId order by CreatedUtcDateTime) as old_value
      from history h
     ) h
where CreatedUtcDateTime >= '2018-01-01' and
      CreatedUtcDateTime < '2019-02-01' and
      old_value <> value;  -- I can't tell if this is necessary
```

The important point is that the time filtering goes in the outer query not the inner one.  Otherwise, you'll miss the first change during the period.

Comment: Thank you. That works, this is way more efficient than my query, but still it uses Index Scan. Is there any possible way I can make it to use Index Seek? I do understand that in should scan a big number of rows though, so maybe this is not possible at all.

Comment: @Smooyk . . . I don't think so.  I think this problem will require scanning the data.